# How can I select columns/rows with the opposite of the column/row names in R?

Tags: r

I have a matrix or a data-frame with specific column names. With a vector containing some of the column names, I can easily address those columns of the matrix. But is there as well a simple way to address the opposite columns, which are not listed in the vector:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1:12), ncol=4)
colnames(mat) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
not_target_col <- c("a", "b")
```

in this case I like to have the columns `c` and `d`. 
I search something like this, without making the extra step:

```
pos <- colnames(mat) != not_target_col
mat[,pos]
```

**Additional explanation**

I like to make it more clear: When I have a numeric vector I can get the opposite when I add `*-1`

```
not_target_col <- c(1,2)
mat[,not_target_col * -1]
```

There is as well a technique like this when I use a logical vector. Here I just have to add a `!`.

```
not_target_col <- c(T,T,F,F)
mat[,!not_target_col]
```

Comment: @akrun definitly, what i do now?

Comment: Nothing you can do.  Somebody will dupe tag it

Comment: I added another solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `setdiff` between column names (`colnames`) and `not_target_col` to get the column names which do not match with `not_target_col`.

```
setdiff(colnames(mat), not_target_col)
#[1] "c" "d"
```

If we need to select those columns from the matrix

```
mat[, setdiff(colnames(mat), not_target_col)]

#     c  d
#[1,] 7 10
#[2,] 8 11
#[3,] 9 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `%in%`

```
mat[, !colnames(mat) %in% not_target_col]
#     c  d
#[1,] 7 10
#[2,] 8 11
#[3,] 9 12
```